# Excel is not updating cells, options > formula > workbook calculation set to automatic

Tags: excel

The usual answer to this question is to turn formulas to automatic.  This, in my case, is not working.

The second usual answer is that there is some macro that is affecting the Excel settings.  This is not the case with my problem (xlsx file).

Office 2010, my simple formula is not updating.

The formula is:

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(OFFSET(MainCopy!AG$3,$A77,0)),"")
```

Everything else is updating in the spreadsheet.  The cell in MainCopy has the correct value.  The value displayed is the value before I updated the information on MainCopy.  When I put new information in MainCopy, the value on this page stayed the same.

I have:

- Researched this issue on the internet - all solutions easy to find do not address this problem
- Pressed F9 (did nothing)
- Pressed Shift-F9 (did nothing)
- Turned calculation to manual and hit all combinations of F9 (did nothing)
- Turned calculation back to automatic (did nothing)
- Saved with a new name (did nothing)
- Re-updated data on MainCopy (did nothing)
- Selected the cell and hit F9 (did nothing)
- Put my cursor in the box and hit enter (UPDATED VALUE CORRECTLY)

I cannot put my cursor in each box and hit enter, there are too many boxes.  In addition, this is creating a major error trap in a spreadsheet that needs to be correct.  Is there some obscure setting that has been triggered in this file that is creating this issue?

Comment: Please note that neither value is an error, so it is not an issue with IFERROR

Comment: I assume that you don't have circular references?

Comment: And what happens if you press Ctrl-Alt-F9 (calculateFull) or Ctrl-Alt-Shift-F9 (rebuild dependency trees then full calculate)?

Comment: That is correct, no circular references and circular references are not allowed.  The only thing unusual about this file is that it was marked as final, then unmarked as final.  Other references are updating fine though, it is just this one page.

Comment: @Charles Williams Both Ctrl-Alt-F9 and Ctrl-Alt-Shift-F9 updated the cells and made it so they are updating correctly.  After saving and reopening, the spreadsheet is still working correctly.  Thanks! But any idea why this would have happened?

Comment: Probably the dependency tree got corrupted for this formula: so rebuilding them solved the problem.

Comment: I've expanded this answer-in-comments into a full answer, so that this question can (hopefully) become an answered question.

Comment: I'm seeing this within a table with =[@column1]*[@column2] formulas - and found out by accident that resizing the table fixes this. Anyone got an idea if this is the same issue?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I had this happen in a worksheet today. Neither F9 nor turning on Iterative Calculation made the cells in question update, but double-clicking the cell and pressing Enter did. I searched the Excel Help and found this in the help article titled *Change formula recalculation, iteration, or precision:*

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F9</kbd>:
>
> Recalculate all formulas in all open workbooks, regardless of whether they have changed since the last recalculation.
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F9</kbd>:
>
> Check dependent formulas, and then recalculate all formulas in all open workbooks, regardless of whether they have changed since the last recalculation.

So I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F9</kbd>, and sure enough, all of my non-recalculating formulas finally recalculated!

Comment: I have the same issue when I generate Excel file from crash (ZIP/XML) using following formula =COUNTIFS('Simulation Summary'!AA:AA;"OK";'Simulation Summary'!AB:AB;$A3). The Dan Henderson solve my problem after Excel has load the file. Thanks! I must now find a solution to update value before file is loaded into Excel.

Comment: Had an issue with an old SSIS package that was inserting data into a sheet, but formulas weren't updating with all of the standard methods. This seems to have permanently solved the issue even after inserting more data, thank you!

Comment: All - I had a similar issue when using python and openpyxl to generate formula in a spreadsheet.  The answer that may suggest some alternative approaches here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56553596/aggregate-formula-not-automatically-calculating-when-written-to-results-spreadsh

Comment: What is the VBA for that key-combo?

Answer (score 12):

the ctrl alt f9  , is the temporary solution , going to options-formula-auto calculate is the right way, that    option turned manual, because some shortcut key on  being pressed by mistake turns automatic to manual

Comment: For Excel 2016, Formulas -> Calculation Options -> Automatic

Comment: That's only the right way if calculate is actually set to manual. I had formulas glitch on a spreadsheet where it was already set to automatic and none of the calculate buttons or settings fixed the issue. Ctrl+Alt+F9 was the only thing that got it working again.

Comment: The question specifically states that calculation is already set to Automatic. So this answer is correct for a different question, but not for this question.

Answer (score 6):

Add this to your macro and it will recalculate all the cells and formulae.

```
Call Application.CalculateFullRebuild
```

Hope it has been already fixed.

**PS** The above code is for the people looking for a macro to solve the issue.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-calculatefullrebuild-method-excel/

Comment: Obsolete `Call` is not required.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Files->Options->Formulas-> Calculation Options / Set Workbook calculation to Automatic

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that excel column was showing me `"=concatenate(A1,B1)"` instead of 
it 's value after concatenation.

I added a space after "," like this `=concatenate(A1,  B1)` and it worked.

This is just an example that solved my problem.

Try and let me know if it works for you as well.

Sometimes it works without space as well, but at other times it doesn't.

Comment: it is likely just the trigger described in the OPs question when updating a cell by not changing anything actually!

Comment: I have seen this happen when a cell is assigned the "Text" format. Excel generally assumes that cells marked as Text should not be parsed for formulas. If this is the case, change the cell to "General" instead.

Answer (score 0):

The field is formatted as 'Text', which means that formulas aren't evaluated. Change the formatting to something else, press F2 on the cell and Enter.

Answer (score 0):

On Excel 2016, using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> work well.

This combination call `Application.CalculateFull()` VBA Excel function.

This can be time consuming if other Excel files are loaded because all Excel sheets of all opened workbooks will be calculated again!

I have searched a function to calculate a specific sheet but I don't have found something!

Answer (score 0):

## In short

**creating or moving some/all reference containing worksheets (out and) into your workbook** may solve it.

## More details

I had this issue after copying some sheets from "template" sheets/workbooks to some new "destination" workbook (the templates were provided by other users!):

I got:

- workbook *WbTempl1*

  - with sheet *WsTempl1RefDef* (defining the references used e.g. in *WsTempl2RefUsr* below, e.g. `project` on `A1`)
- workbook *WbTempl2* (above references do not exist, because *WsTempl1RefDef* is not contained nor externally referenced, e.g. like <s>`WbTempl2.Names("project").refersTo="C:\WbTempl1.xls]'WsTempl1RefDef!A1"`</s>)

  - contains sheet *WsTempl2RefUsr* (uses inexisting global references, e.g. `=project`)

and wanted to create a *WbDst* to copy *WsTempl1RefDef* and *WsTempl2RefUsr* into it.

---

The following **did not work**:

1. create workbook *WbDst*
2. copy sheet *WsTempl1RefDef* into it (references were locally created)
3. copy sheet *WsTempl2RefUsr* into it

Here as well the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>(<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>)<kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>F9</kbd> nor `Application.CalculateFullRebuild` worked on *WbDst*.

---

The following **worked**:

1. create workbook *WbDst*
2. **move (not copy)** sheet *WsTempl1RefDef* into *WbTempl2*

   - (we do not have to save them)
3. copy sheet *WsTempl1RefDef* into *WbDst*
4. copy sheet *WsTempl2RefUsr* into *WbDst*

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue with a VLOOKUP. The field I was using to VLOOKUP was formatted as a custom field. Excel was saying it was a number stored as text. Clearing this error (selecting all fields with the error, beginning with the first one with the error and clicking change to Number even though I didn't really want it to be!) fixed it.

Comment: I tried a similar approach but it did not work. However, after copying the same formulas a second time in the cells did appear to solve the problem.

Comment: it is likely just the trigger described in the OPs question when updating a cell by not changing anything actually!