# IF statement error despite the check being FALSE and the [value_if_false] being 0 or 1

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

For my own amusement I am trying to automate a project from work to learn more about excel vba.  For the primary tab of data, I have an import function that drags in the relevant columns from another sheet for columns A through J.  After that, there are a bunch of columns already set up to manipulate the the data being imported.

One of the calculation columns is supposed to return a basic 0/1 flag if the related company has been a client for >20 years.  However, it ended up being a very slow UDF, so I wrapped it in an If statement to check if any other flags are false first so I can skip the slow calculation if the claim is already being eliminated.  It worked fine before I went back to tweaking the import macro.  Here is the function:

```
=IF( Q2*O2*N2 = 0, 0, IF(CompanyYears(J2, End_of_Claim_Period, Analysis_Width) >= Valid_Co_Years, 1, 0))
```

So now after the data import the only two results the column gives are 0 and #VALUE!.  However, the 'evaluate function' step through confused me more.  Turns out that for every value error, the 3 flags from columns Q/O/N are 1.  So first the evaluate looks up and multiplies those 3 flags, gets 1=0 -> FALSE.  The next thing it does is resolve what the named range End_of_Claim_Period points to.  While it successfully changes it to a cell address, the outer IF statement's value_if_true changes from 0 to #N/A at the same time.  The inner if statement continues just fine to a result of 0 or 1, and finally the statement

```
=IF(FALSE, #N/A, 1)
```

or

```
=IF(FALSE, #N/A, 0)
```

gets evaluated to #VALUE!.

Also, if I try to filter that column to see only the rows with a #VALUE! response, it correctly reevaluates them to the appropriate 0/1 values.  I tried having the vba code filter then unfilter the row automatically but that leaves the errors in place still.

**Update:** While working on something else I came across a somewhat similar question here:

[Excel is not updating cells, options > formula > workbook calculation set to automatic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32590616/excel-is-not-updating-cells-options-formula-workbook-calculation-set-to-aut)

I added Application.CalculateFull in at the end of the macro, which technically solved my problem, albeit for a notable performance hit.

Comment: An `#N/A` error is not `#N/A!` and if best represented by `NA()`.

Comment: Or `=NV()` for the people using German language pack.

Comment: Ah, thank you Jeeped.  I never noticed a difference before.  Yes, the final IF statement is IF(FALSE, #N/A, 1)