# Excel with VBA, Workbook calculations on Manual, shift-F9 does not work

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large excel file with vba codes. When opening the file, excel automatically started calculating, hence it took minutes to even open the file. I set the workbook calculations in File/Options to Manual which solved the problem. However, when I run the macro now, it does not update the cells. Instead it puts the correct formulas in each cell without calculating to find the right value.

Strangely, Shift F9 does not work anymore. Yet when I go to one of the cells and press F2+ENTER the correct value is displayed.

Any idea how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel is not updating cells, options > formula > workbook calculation set to automatic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32590616/excel-is-not-updating-cells-options-formula-workbook-calculation-set-to-aut)

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+F9 does not work unfortunately

Comment: What about just `F9` on its own? If it works, be prepared for a long recalculation time. Alternatively, try putting `Application.Calculate` in/after the relevant line in your macro.

Comment: Yeah, was wondering about `F9`, too. If that works, there are probably some formulae referencing cells on other sheets that are themselves `dirty` but not reevaluated by `Shift+F9`. Although `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+F9` should have solved that issue... We're stabbing in the dark here.

Comment: F9 doesn't work either - no idea why. Peculiarly when I open an empty new workbook, keep the manual calculating settings, and perform some simple calculations SHIFT+F9 does not work either. Only when the option is back on Automatic calculations. No idea whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

creating or moving some/all reference containing worksheets (out and) into your workbook may solve it.
More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56549247/1915920